# Do utility classes in java follow encapsulation mechanism?

Tags: java, oop

Encapsulation describes the ability of an object to hide its data and methods from the rest of the world and is one of the fundamental principles of object-oriented programming. In Java, a class encapsulates the fields, which hold the state of an object, and the methods, which define the actions of the object. 
Also, we declare the fields as private so as to prevent the state of an object.

As utility classes only contains the functionality (static methods) and no data members, would it be right to say that utility class do not follow encapsulation mechanism?

Comment: Utility classes aren't object oriented either. They are primarily functional

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation is not a principle or a mechanism.  Wikipedia describes it as "... encapsulation is used to refer to one of two related but distinct notions ..." in the context of OOP.

According to Wikipedia, the two notions are:

> - A language mechanism for restricting direct access to some of the object's components.
> - A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.

Neither of these really apply in the case of (pure) utility classes.

But to saying that *"... utility classes do not follow encapsulation principle"* is misguided, because it implies that encapsulation is a good thing in all cases.   In the case of utility class, it is simply inapplicable.

(And "following a mechanism" does not make sense.)

---

Now I will grant you that different people have attempted to characterize encapsulation (and information hiding, and modularization) over the years, and it is not clear that anyone of these is characterizations *definitive*.

This is another reason that the proposition that *"... utility classes do not follow encapsulation principle"* is misguided.  There is no agreed *definition* of what encapsulation actually means.

Comment: A utility class may have private methods that it uses, but doesn't expose. It may even have private implementations of interfaces or classes that it returns. Whilst a trivial utility class has no need for these things, it is likely most utility classes will have some inaccessible moving parts.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: as you mentioned that most likely utility classes will have some inaccessible moving parts - i assume you are pointing to the behavior over here as it would not have any state.

Comment: @greenHorn indeed - a utility class definitely should be stateless, but encapsulation is not just about state.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: most of the definitions around encapsulation states - hiding the state of an object (achieved by using private data members), so it is safe to say that encapsulation is not only about state, it is also related to hiding the behavior too ( in cases where classes are stateless)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: i wanted your opinion on the definition of encapsulation, reason i asked it again.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I see your point.  However, I would refer to private methods in a utility class as modularization or information hiding rather than encapsulation.  Certainly the Wikipedia definition implies that encapsulation is about state AND methods.

Comment: Seems a semantic argument at this point. But it does serve to show that things aren't that clear cut.

Comment: Exactly.  I have updated my answer to the effect that there isn't a consensus on the meaning of "encapsulation" ... which is another reason why the proposition is misguided.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a utility class is a class that defines a set of methods that perform common functions.By the OOP principles, an object should contain both data and a behavior performed over that data.Utility classes are just behavior, all the data are passed as inputs. It is in no way Object Oriented, it is a more of a Procedural way of thinking.